# A part of CSS won't work after adding a background-image

Tags: html, css

Good afternoon,

I've been using HTML and CSS for a couple of weeks now and recently came across a problem that I have no clue about how to fix. Before I added a background-image, the contact id worked just fine and the CSS loaded properly. But after adding the image in the pages class, the CSS contact id didn't work anymore. Also in the element inspector the properties of the contact id were not there. 
So I'm not sure If I missed something in between the link of HTML and CSS or that I coded it in the wrong order. The code below is after the contact id stopped working.

```
.pages {
    background-image: url("img/background.png");
}

#contact {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #171717;
    text-align: right;          
}

.sidebar {
   font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin: auto;
   background-color: #212121;
   width: 100px;
   transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li, a {
  text-decoration: none;    
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

i.fa {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #565656;
  color: #212121;
  z-index:1;
}

span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #000000;
  transition:all ease 0.5s;
  line-height: 90px;
  &::after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 45px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #000;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
}

&:hover {
  i.fa {
    background-color: #000;
  }

  span {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sidebar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" 
    integrity="sha384- 
    mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz" 
    rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i> 
            <span>Opleiding</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> 
            <span>Werkervaring</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb"></i> 
            <span>Vaardigheden</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pages">

    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <a href="#" id="contact">contact</a>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your time and hope you guys and women can help me out. By the way English isn't my native language so I hope I explained it clearly.

Comment: your code seems okay. but your .`page` could overlay the absolute footer . (empty here doesn't show any issue).. Would consider using flex or grid ?

Comment: Seems to display for me too. Some formatting issues if you add some content, but it's visible. What happens if you change the `#footer` CSS identifier to `.footer`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @G-Cyr, I will consider CSS grid, hope it will be much more organized

Comment: @MichaelMcMullin Thank you, I can see my footer again when switching to a class. Do you any tips for me on the formatting?

Comment: Just some padding or a margin to make sure it clears the sidebar on the left.

Comment: @MichaelMcMullin It worked. Thank you for your time. I became a little wiser hahah

Answer (score 0):

> Dirk van Houten
>
> *I will consider CSS grid, hope it will be much more organized*

If you think grid is okay for you, it can indeed avoid the use of position and sides effects.

example:

```css
/* grid instead position: */

body {
margin:0;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 20px;
}
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.footer {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}
.pages {
  overflow: auto;
}

/* end grid system */


/* position and coordonates, so transform are removed from codes */
.pages {
  background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/50x50");
}
#contact {
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: #171717;
  text-align: right;
}
.sidebar {
  font-family: "Yanone Kaffeesatz", sans-serif;
  background-color: #212121;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}
.sidebar a {
  position: relative;
}
li,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
}
i.fa {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #565656;
  color: #212121;
  z-index: 1;
}
a span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #000000;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  line-height: 90px;
}
a span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 45px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #000;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
:hover i.fa {
  background-color: #000;
}
a:hover span {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" 
    integrity="sha384- 
    mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz" 
    rel="stylesheet">

<div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i> 
            <span>Opleiding</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> 
            <span>Werkervaring</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb"></i> 
            <span>Vaardigheden</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pages">
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <a href="#" id="contact">contact</a>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example and the effort. I will analyze it and look more into it